# Can not write to xml if user is not admin in java application

Tags: java, installation, inno-setup, file-permissions, user-permissions

This is the first time I have finished java application for our customers and I have created this application's setup. I have created project folder, libs and xml files in C:\ProgramFiles\MyProject folder. I'm also creating shortcut in desktop for this project and I'm starting this application with this shortcut.

In my application I'm using xml file that they must have properties of reading and writing. This xml files are in C:\ProgramFiles\MyProject folder. When I want to access this xml file for writing I can not do that. I analyzed this files and I see that there is no permission for user. I'm executing project as an administrator all the time. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Do you NEED to be in program files folder?

Comment: Move the XML file to within the application's classpath. Assuming you are building a .jar, include the XML file in the jar.

Comment: Yes I need this. I'm creating setup with Inno Setup Compiler. When I'm creating this setup I'm loading necessary folders in this setup and when I run this setup, program files folder have been creating by this setup and this xml files in program files folder. Is there another way to do this ?